# my div is out from border-radius

Tags: html, css

Here is my problem:

I have a `<h1>` inside `<div>` but when I set a `border-radius` in `<div>` the `<h1>` is out from the `div`, here is my code:

```
<div class="test"><h1 class="text">test</h1></div>

.test{
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.test .text{
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

and this is live run

http://jsfiddle.net/n3aru/

Comment: Please show us what you expect the result to be...

Comment: `margin: auto` only works with elements that have a height/width other than auto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your text is actually not outside your div:

[image]

The visuality has just changed, not the structure.

You may want to position your text to the center:

```
.test{
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

    text-align: center;
}

.test .text{
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;

    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3aru/6/)

*Centering trick: http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/*

Answer (score 1):

```
.test{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works with this, thank you very very much :D

Comment: @user3164971 Seriously? You accepted this? deleting my answer, you ask something else, and you wanted something else

Comment: Add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin of the inner div. Something like this:

```
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:50px;
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more concise way to center that text (if that's what you're after):

```
.test .text
{
    margin: 0; /* Only need this because h1 elements have default margin. */
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3aru/7/) (taken from @nkmol as a base).